# Integrating $\int_0^3 \frac{\sqrt x}{\sqrt x + \sqrt{3 - x}} \,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

This integral is unique for me and I was quite wondering how an integral below would result into "$3/2$".

Show that 
$$
\int_0^3 \frac{\sqrt x}{\sqrt x + \sqrt{3 - x}} \ dx =\frac{3}{2}
$$

Comment: In what sense is this integral unique to you ?

Comment: It's not really unique - replace $3$ by $a$ (any real number) in the upper limit and under the root, then you will have $I=\frac{a}{2}$

Comment: It's actually new to me. I never seen any integrals such like this on Leithold's TC7, or maybe I never see it before within the textbook.

Comment: Claude, this is unique for me because if we use trigonometric functions, we always get pi/4.

Comment: See also: [Substitution Integral: $\int_0^3\frac {\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{3-x}} dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2273100)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute with $y=3-x$ gives

$$I=-\int_3^0 \frac{\sqrt{3-y}}{\sqrt y +\sqrt{3-y}} dy=\int_0^3  \frac{\sqrt{3-y}}{\sqrt y +\sqrt{3-y}} dy$$

So

$$2I=3$$

Comment: Ohhh! Now it's clear! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Use property $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ = $\int_{a}^{b}f(a+b-x)dx$

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd multiply by $\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{3-x}$ and integrate by parts. And I'd be careful about the domain (separate it in two parts, one $x<\frac{3}{2}$ and the other $x>\frac{3}{2}$)

But I am sure there are plenty of other tricks applicable (variable change for instance)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint for the standard method:**

The domain of the integrand is $\;0\le x\le 3$. Rewrite it as $\; \dfrac 1{1+\sqrt{\dfrac3x-1}}$ and use the substitution
$$\newcommand\d{\,{\mathrm d\mkern1mu}} u=\sqrt{\dfrac3x-1}\iff x=\frac3{u^2+1},\enspace u\ge 0,\qquad \d x=-\frac{6u}{(u^2+1)^2}\d u$$
So one obtains
$$\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{6u}{(1+u)(1+u^2)^2}\d u.$$
There remains to use decomposition into partial fractions.